Como actualizo registros en laravel, relaciona muchos a muchos?
Tengo ya creado el crud supplier y todo bien con eso, ahora con el crud de productos ya hice el create y e me lee los registros, a la hora de actualizar productos no me hace nada, me recarga y deja el mismo registro. La relacion es muchos productos muchos suppliers, tabla pívot productos_x_suppliers. Cabe destacar que a productos vienen las tablas estante y subcategoría. cuando hago el dd($request->all());
 public function update(Request $request, Producto $producto)
        {

            dd($request->all());
            $request->validate([
                'nombreProducto' => "required|string|min:3|unique:productos,nombreProducto,{$producto->id}",
                'precioUnitario' => 'required|string|min:3',
                'stockMinimo' => 'required|string|min:3',
                'stockMaximo' => 'required|string|min:3',
                'cantidad' => 'required|string|min:3',
                'subcategoria_id' => 'required|exists:subcategorias,id',
                'estante_id' => 'required|exists:estantes,id',
                'supplier_name' => 'array',
                'supplier_name.*' => 'exists:suppliers,id'
            ]); 

            $producto->update([

                'nombreProducto' => $request->input('nombreProducto'),
                'precioUnitario' => $request->input('precioUnitario'),
                'stockMinimo' => $request->input('stockMinimo'),
                'stockMaximo' => $request->input('stockMaximo'),
                'cantidad' => $request->input('cantidad'),
                'subcategoria_id' => $request->input('subcategoria_id'),
                'estante_id' => $request->input('estante_id'),

                
            ]);

            $supplierId = $request->input('supplier_id');
    
            // Sincronizar los suppliers con el producto
            if ($supplierId) {
                $producto->suppliers()->sync($supplierId);
            } else {
                // Si no hay suppliers seleccionados, eliminar todas las relaciones
                $producto->suppliers()->sync([]);
            }

    
        return redirect()->back()->with('msjupdate', 'producto actualizado con éxito');
}

cuando hago el dd($request->all()) me trae lo siguiente, al parecer si me esta tomando los datos bien pero no me actualiza
array:10 [▼ // app\Http\Controllers\ProductoController.php:95
  "_token" => "wy1LRCp4sZS4hN0YqbZPEN1ekn6OTcyXaxCkIB93"
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "subcategoria_id" => "19"
  "nombreProducto" => "pepitonas"
  "precioUnitario" => "234"
  "stockMinimo" => "12"
  "stockMaximo" => "20"
  "cantidad" => "15"
  "estante_id" => "4"
  "supplier_name" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "20"
  ]
]

